# The forward slashes are ignored in the local environment but not in the global environment

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, url

I'm writing an app in my google app engine which get 2 parameters and write the first one to the app if the user is an admin and the second otherwise:

The app works like that:

```
import webapp2
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import users

class ShowPara(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self,para1,para2):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if users.is_current_user_admin():
            message_text = para1
        else:
            message_text = para2
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(message_text)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/(.*)/(.*)', ShowPara)],
                              debug=True)
```

When I run this app on the local google app engine launcher with the following URL:

```
localhost:25080///////////////////a/b
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
//////////////////a
```

When I run the exact same app after deploying it on google servers with the following URL (same one):

```
https://hw01-2020.appspot.com///////////////////a/b
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
a
```

It's important to note that I'm forcing login in my YAML file by the follwong code:

```
login: required
```

Why when I run it locally it won't ignore the slashes and when I run it after deploy it it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some servers automatically collapse multiple consecutive `/` chars into a single one. Even SO: [The forward slashes are ignored in the local environment but not in the global environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217866//////////the-forward-slashes-are-ignored-in-the-local-environment-but-not-in-the-global-e). It's possible that GAE's frontent does the same.

You could adjust your pattern to account for that and always get the parameters without the '/' char in them:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/*(.[^/]*)/*(.[^/]*)', ShowPara)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Hi @תומר לב, if Dan Cornilescu's answer was useful, please accept it.